# 404 Not Found - nginx/1.12.2 - Rails Api application - Routing Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, nginx, capistrano, passenger

I am not able to get access the API.

I am Using the Nginx and Passenger. I am deploying it by using Capistrano.

My Default file in Nginx sites available

```
##
##
# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80;

    root /var/www/xyz/current/public;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    # index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_env    staging;
    server_name ec2-258-255-77-987.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    # include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    # # With php7.0-cgi alone:
    # fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    # # With php7.0-fpm:
    # fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    # deny all;
    #}
}
```

I am not able to access the API from the same server and got 404

Please Help me

**Edit**

I checked the error log and its shows routing error.

my application is at var/www/xyz/current

What is wrong with my routes?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your NGINX is not configured correctly to handle your app's traffic, you have configured it only for assets in the way it is. You should add a upstream socket that your app should listen to. First you add a `upstream` block pointing to your application's socket in `default` file:

```
## Start of file
upstream my_app {
    server unix:/tmp/capistrano.passenger.sock fail_timeout=0;
    ## You can use a HTTP address if you don't want your application listening into sockets.
    # server http://127.0.0.1:8000 fail_timeout=0;
}
# other stuff like: server { ...
```

Then separate the streams of assets and application serving to separate it's configurations and create a `server` scoped `try_files` including your application upstream:

```
server {
    # other stuff...
    location ^~ /assets/ {
        gzip_static on;
        expires max;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
    }
    try_files $uri $uri/ @my_app;
    location @my_app {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://my_app;
    }
    # other stuff...
}
```

Don't forget to remove your existing `location / {...}` block.